# Why my email confirmation token is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```cs
[HttpGet("confirm/{userId}/{token}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string token)
{
    User user = _userService.GetById(userId);
    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.
    ConfirmEmailAsync(user, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token));
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return Ok("Email confirmed successfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Error while confirming your email!";
        return SignOut();
    }
}
```

So my token is invalid at Identity result Result. Why is this the case and how can i solve this? I think it has to do with that the token is not in the database. I am using asp .net core.

Comment: The default token is invalid to be included in a URL path, so it's not clear from the code here what you're doing exactly or what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

Your token maybe expired.

You can create an class like this to create a custom token provider and set expiration time

```cs
public class CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
            IOptions<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions> options) 
            : base(dataProtectionProvider, options)
    {
    }
}
public class EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{
    public EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions()
    {
        Name = "EmailDataProtectorTokenProvider";
        TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    }
}
```

then register this class after `services.AddIdentity` method like this

```cs
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(identityOptions =>
            {
                 //DoSomething
            })
            .AddTokenProvider<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>>("EmailDataProtectorTokenProvider");
```

This token expires after one day